# Différence entre « moquer » et « se moquer »

Tags: vocabulaire

Je m'aperçois que la plupart du temps, *se moquer* est employé, plutôt que [*moquer*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/moquer/52545?q=moquer#52410). Que change la présence du pronom réflexif *se* ? 
La définition du Larousse n'aborde pas ces questions. Par exemple, est-il possible d'écrire :

> [C'est l'hôpital qui **<s>se</s> moque** de la charité](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_pot_calling_the_kettle_black)

Answer (score 2):

Jusqu'au début du 20<sup>e</sup> siècle, l'usage transitif était plus fréquent à l'écrit (je ne suis pas certain si l'« éclipse » de l'usage pronominal mentionnée par Grevisse (*Le bon Usage*, 14<sup>e</sup> edition, §779 c. 1<sup>o</sup>) entre le 17<sup>e</sup> et le 20<sup>e</sup> siècle se retrouvait aussi à l'oral), mais cette tendance s'est inversée, et *moquer* est aujourd'hui pour la plupart des usagers un verbe strictement pronominal, au même titre que *s'arroger* ou *s'égosiller*, alors que l'usage transitif [est noté comme vieux ou littéraire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moquer).

Ce n'est toutefois pas le seul verbe où les deux formes se rencontrent. Grevisse cite ainsi (je ne note que ceux qui sont les plus communs) *soucier*, *chamailler* et, dans la direction inverse, *s'accaparer* et le canadianisme *se mériter*.

Answer (score 1):

Selon le Robert, *moquer* est employé comme synonyme de *railler, ridiculiser*, pour tourner en ridicule, traiter comme un objet de dérision, où plaisanter :

> Il se vit bafoué, berné, sifflé, moqué, joué. *La Fontaine*.

Pour l'emploi de *se moquer* les synonymes sont :

- *bafouer, blaguer*
- familier : *charrier, chiner*
- vieilli ou plus littéraire : *dauber, se gausser, gouailler, narguer, persifler, railler*
- *rire de*
- *contrefaire, parodier*
- *autodérision* (se moquer de soi-même)

Avec le sens de ne pas de soucier de ne pas faire cas de :

- *dédaigner, se désintéresser, mépriser*
- *braver* (se moquer du qu'en dira-t-on)

Tromper ou essayer de tromper (quelqu'un) avec désinvolture :

- *avoir, berner, duper, rouler*

Pour un usage courant :

> *Se moquer* : je me moque d'autrui.
>   *Moquer* : on se moque de moi.

Dans ce cas c'est *l’hôpital qui se moque de la charité*...
... et la charité qui se trouve *moquée* par l'hôpital.